# timestamp with mongoskin how to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

For those who want to query for timestamp here's how you do that:

```
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e43a21d84782019413162ed"), "a" : { "t" : 1313055261000, "i" : 1 } }
> db.foo.find({'a': {'$gte': new Timestamp(new Date(2011, 8-1, 11), 0) } })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e43a21d84782019413162ed"), "a" : { "t" : 1313055261000, "i" : 1 } }
> db.foo.find({'a': {'$gte': new Timestamp(new Date(2011, 8-1, 12), 0) } })
```

i find that example in mongodb's page... but if i want to insert a timestamp in mongodb using mongoskin following the example???

i try this:

```
db.collection('times').insert({time: new Timestamp(new Date('2012-08-06'),0)})
```

this is the error:

```
ReferenceError: Timestamp is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's because `Timestamp` is not defined. It's neither part of JavaScript nor Node. You should define it before using. This should work:

```js
var mongoskin = require('mongoskin');
var Timestamp = mongoskin.BSONPure.Timestamp;
```

Note that this `Timestamp`s are for [internal db use only](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Timestamp+data+type); why do you need them, when there are `Date.now()` and `new Date().getTime()`?

Anyway, here's a link with some more details — http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/timestamp.html.

Comment: becos i need to search for documents by date()... there is anyway to put new date() and search by date for example: documents newer than 2012-09-01

Comment: @andrescabana86, yes, you can `db.collection.find({date: {$gt: d}})`, where `d` is any `Date`. You could also use timestamps (not those in Mongo, but those returned by `Date().getTime()`).